# Issue getting subdomains to route properly in Apache 2.4

Tags: python, apache, flask

I'm setting up some simple Flask apps and trying to make them availble on the Web via a subdomain.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

- Traffic to app.example.com/friend/friends/v1 to route through to
  3.8.16.17/friend/friends/v1, run a specific Python Flask app and respond with JSON response.
- Traffic to app.example.com/family/families/v1 to route through to
  3.8.16.17/family/families/v1 and run a specific Python Flask app and respond with JSON response.

Using Apache2.4 and Flask (Python 3.6) on a Windows Server 2012 R2 AWS EC2 machine, I have done the following:
 - Changed my service provider’s DNS settings to point app.example.com
   at 3.8.16.17
 - Set Apache to listen on port 80.
 - Set up the virtualhosts conf file (httpd-vhosts.conf).

The virtual hosts file looks as follows:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin enquiries@example.com
    ServerName  3.8.16.17:80
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL

    WSGIScriptAlias /friend/friends/v1 "C:/Projects/friend/friends/v1/web.wsgi"
    DocumentRoot C:/Projects/friend/friends /v1
    <Directory "C:/Projects/friend/friends/v1">
        Options -Includes -Indexes -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /family/families/v1 "C:/Projects/family/families/v1/web.wsgi"
    DocumentRoot C:/Projects/family/families/v1
    <Directory "C:/Projects/family/families/v1">
        Options -Includes -Indexes -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "C:/Projects/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/Projects/logs/access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>
```

When I try 3.8.16.17/friend/friends/v1 or 3.8.16.17/family/families/v1 in a browser, everything works exactly as it should and the vhosts file is being read and acted on.

When I try app.example.com/friend/friends/v1 or app.example.com/family/families/v1 in a browser, I get “Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource” and the address bar URL simply changes to 3.8.16.17.

What am I doing wrong?  What setting am I leaving out?

As an Apache newbie, I need some help.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want your VirtualHost to respond to app.example.com, you need to set that as the ServerName or ServerAlias.

Comment: I thought that too - doesn't work.  I just get “Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource” and the address bar URL simply changes to 3.8.16.17.

Comment: You'll get that in the address bar as that is what you have identified the server name as. The server name is usually the domain name, not the IP address.